# Application login dialog in browser but not in DOM, how can I interact with it using automation tools

Tags: asp.net, selenium-webdriver, browser, awtrobot

I am writing some automation in Selenium (Java) for an internal application which is quite old. I encountered something that I can't solve with any tools in Selenium and with general Googling, nothing is coming up. I'm on a Mac (OS: macOS Ventura 13.3.1) using primarily Chrome, but the same thing happens on other browsers. This is a web application hosted on an internal server.

When the URL is passed to the browser on about:blank (see HTML below), a dialog box opens to accept login credentials (see attached image). However, there is no HTML document associated with the login which is loaded on the DOM. The browser's main viewing panel is completely empty and the only thing in the DOM is about:blank.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

You can see the login dialog box and interact with it directly by clicking in the username and password textboxes and clicking the buttons, however Selenium can't interact with this object. One of the developers who works on that app said it was around before he started and he doesn't even know how it works, but suspects it's an ASP form of some kind running on "default browser, not a web page" and that it's a .NET application (even though we are a Java shop)

[image: Login dialog form]

I Googled for nearly an entire day, to no avail. I created a custom Robot class for sending keys to it, but need to figure out how to target it. I've even tried sending ALT-TAB using Robot but it doesn't target focus on the Username textbox, even though that textbox appears to have focus and a cursor in it.

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to identify this object and target it with automation tools would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String un = "<username>";
String pwd = "<password>";
// appending username, password with URL
String url = "https://" + un + ":" + pwd + "@" + "<enter actual URL>";
driver.get(url);
```

Syntax:

```
https://username:password@URL
```

You don't need to separately locate the username, password elements and action on it. The above code should ideally log you in.

Comment: I tried compiling a URL request directly in the browser and it throws "This site can’t be reached - https’s server IP address could not be found." When I do this in code, Selenium doesn't like it and throws the following exception: "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"

Answer (score 0):

Well, asp.net does allow .net code to run and intercept requests BEFORE they are sent to web server for processing. (that's part of how application pools are setup).

So, often things like say a Image handler is created. These "things" thus run before IIS gets the request. Since that looks "much" like the windows domain logon, it most likely your authentication model being used here. (and that like other handlers can run before IIS gets the request - that's how authentication handlers can be added to existing web sites).

So, what authentication model is the site using? (look at web config - it should show this information). Are logons in database (say FBA (forms based authentication) or are these windows domain based? If you use windows domain based authentication, then quite sure the dialog is produced by the authentication system. (I mean, hit f12, browser debug tools - hover over that dialog - what does the markup show???).

So, best guess is that dialog comes from the authentication being used - and looks to be windows authentication (windows domain) based.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. That helps describe why I'm seeing this from a "web app". The developer provided this info from the web.config. The problem I now have is how the heck to I interact with it using automation tools (ex. Robot)?
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
<deny users="?"/>
</authorization>

Comment: Well, setup of web security and preventing pages being used by non logged user's and that of now trying to automate the logon? Build a web api, or something else. Beyond lame and silly to attempt to fill out some logon form with "robot" when you have the source and site to develop with.  Why would you use something like robot when you have control and the source code to the site that you can change anything you want?

Comment: Additionally, no dev tools interact with this form at all on multiple browsers. There is nothing on the page, no inspection or debugging interacts with this form at all

Comment: The owner of the application and source code is in another division, I don't have access to it. The developer reports directly to that division's management and I have no say, but am tasked with trying to automate the application. There is no likelihood that I can direct any work be done on this app. It's not lameness or silliness, it's a constraint I can't change. Robot was an attempt to send keystrokes, but your suggestion is not a solution, given my constraints. Thanks for the initial info that helped describe the problem, but your additional comments are not really an answer to the issue.

Comment: Well, then your hands are tied. They are using windows domain and windows network security. As  result, anyone internal probably does not even have to logon. By their very nature of being part of that windows domain network, then I suspect they don't even see that logon. However, if they are outside of the company network, then a logon will have to be provided. The whole point of windows authentication is that users as a general rule don't have to logon to anything to use such resources.  However, if any user is outside of that windows network, then that loggon will no doubt be triggered.

Comment: Assuming that users don't see that logon (unless outside of the network), then I would suggest a VPN. That way, you should be able to hit any part of the web site without seeing a logon.  So, I'm not 100% sure, but I assume that users internal don't get nor see a logon? Only users outside of the network, or not logged in as a valid windows user? (I believe that is the effect you should be seeing). Is this site public facing, or only internal?